# Running chromium with a fake https proxy keep working

Tags: node.js, proxy, puppeteer, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to understand how to correctly configure a `--proxy-server` for chromium and here is what I tried:

```
google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu --proxy-server="https=a:b@1.2.3.4:55555" --headless --dump-dom https://chromium.org
```

Running the browser with a totally fake proxy server credentials `a:b@1.2.3.4:55555` it keeps dumping the dom which is not expected. By contrast, I expected some error related to the proxy server to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome seems to silently ignore your setting because you have specified an invalid proxy server `https=a:b@1.2.3.4:55555`.

When I use `--proxy-server="https://a:b@1.2.3.4:55555"` I'm not able to able to go to any page as you would expect. It gives me the message `This site can’t be reached` (`ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`).